# Override default date of JqueryUi datepicker

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

I have a datepicker on a page as

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProposedLaunchDate, new { @class = "dateselector", @style = "float:left;" })
```

(This is using the Javascripts from [JQueryui.com](http://Jqueryui.com))

In my model the variable to hold the date is a string (for specific reasons), as

```
 public string ProposedLaunchDate { get; set; }
```

On saving I can save my selected date well.

However on redisplaying , in the model I get the value I saved,but on the form the date-picker is taking today's date (and not displaying the value in my model)

Why so ?

How can I correct this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, jQuery `datepicker` will show *currentDate* as *selected*.  Inorder to set our custom date to datepicker, you have use the option called `setDate` provided by datepicker.

```
$(".dateselector").datepicker('setDate', '04/11/2014');
                                              |
      Make sure about the dateFormat__________|
```